# iOS PDF activity sheet?

Tags: ios, pdf, android-activity

Once I generate a PDF in my code, are there any ways to get for free the PDF view controller that Mail shows? Basically to show PDF full screen with a back button and the activity sheet options of Mail, Print, Google Drive and more. Would love to just say to iOS 'here's a PDF, do your thing' but am afraid I have to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: UIWebview can display it for you.

Comment: There's a great open source pdf viewer on Github: https://github.com/vfr/Reader